# AutoMapper CompileMappings throws InvalidOperationException without details to identify map

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

**Summary:**
I'm having trouble debugging a set of AutoMapper maps and need a more "surgical" approach to locating a bad map to fix.

**The Problem:**
The exception message in the `InvalidOperationException` is:

```
No coercion operator is defined between types 'My.Models.WorkViewModel' and 'My.Model.Work'.
```

The stack trace when the exception is thrown is visible in the debugger and is simple and direct, but not overly helpful:

```
ex.StackTrace:
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.GenerateTypeMapExpression(MapRequest mapRequest, TypeMap typeMap)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.BuildExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CompileExecutionPlan(MapRequest mapRequest)
   at AutoMapper.Internal.LockingConcurrentDictionary`2.<>c__DisplayClass2_1.<.ctor>b__1()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at AutoMapper.MapperConfiguration.CompileMappings()
   at IMRS.AutoMapper.ImrsMapperConfiguration..ctor(IEnumerable`1 profileTypes) in C:\Projects\git\imrs\IMRS\IMRS.AutoMapper\ImrsMapperConfiguration.cs:line 74
```

There are no details within the actual exception to help me identify what map is being compiled. There is no `InnerException`, no `Data`, no `StackTrace`, and the `TargetSite` only adds that the expression type was a `System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression` type and the called method name was `GenerateTypeMapExpression`.

**Relevant Code:**
My profile loading uses AutoMapper's ability to load a list of specific profile types derived from `MyProfile` (with a few methods to extend `Profile`), which I build from the public profile classes in my loaded assemblies. Basically, it's a loop:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Initialize a new instance of the ImrsMapperConfiguration class configured to include maps from specified profiles.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="profileTypes">IEnumerable{Type} sequence of profile types to use for configuring maps.</param>
    public ImrsMapperConfiguration(IEnumerable<Type> profileTypes)
    {
        // Load maps from the specified profile type.
        mapperConfig_ = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            foreach (var t in profileTypes)
            {
                try
                {
                    // Instantiate profile type so we can modify the configuration if necessary.
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"Adding maps from profile {t.FullName}.");
                    var ip = (MyProfile)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

                    if (ip is MyProfile)
                    {
                        // Apply additional configuration for all maps in this profile.
                        ip.ForAllMaps((typeMap, mappingExpression) => ip.ConfigurationAction(typeMap, mappingExpression));
                    }

                    cfg.AddProfile(ip);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"Exception adding maps from profile {t.FullName}: {ex.Message}");
                }
            }

            // For backward compatibility, allow collections to be mapped to null instead of empty.
            cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
        });

#if DEBUG
        // Report any errors in type maps. Preferably enabled in Debug build only.
        mapperConfig_.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
#endif
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation($"Compiling maps for mapper configuration.");
            mapperConfig_.CompileMappings();
            //  ^--- InvalidOperationException is thrown when maps are compiled.
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError($"Exception compiling maps: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

The error that instigated this ordeal was `No coercion operator is defined between types 'My.Models.WorkViewModel' and 'My.Model.Work.` I have no map from `My.Models.WorkViewModel` to `My.Model.Work`.

**What I've done so far:**
I have added a map from 'My.Models.WorkViewModel' to 'My.Model.Work' and it does not mitigate the error. My instinct says the error comes from how AutoMapper is generating the type conversions in the mapping for one of the members but I need to locate that map to find and correct it.

I have tried to isolate the map profile that contains a map producing the exception and it's extremely time consuming to repeat the edit->compile->run->debug dance to track down the one bad map before I can even determine the problem and correct it. It's taken me a full day so far.

This is a large .NET 4.8 project with over 800 maps defined, updated from my "before AutoMapper upgrade" code, so the raw exception information is scarcely of any help. Moreover, some of the maps inherit base maps and may be compounding the issue. I've narrowed it down to about 35 maps in 2 profiles.

There is no direct map between the two member types. AutoMapper is inferring the types, but doesn't identify where or why.

**My Question:**
What option(s) in AutoMapper can I enable to tell me what map failed to compile? If none exist, how do I reduce the effort necessary to identify the map with the problem?

Comment: You're not gonna like this, but... it's an idea: you could use AutoMapper from source, and add your own logging at the points of failure. I sure hope someone comes up with a better solution though.

Comment: Don't call `CompileMappings` :) Is should be easy then to see where it fails.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu According to the official documentation, "AutoMapper lazily compiles the type map plans on first map". Why wait for the first map for all of the mappings to be compiled?

Comment: @NPras You're right, I don't like it. Nevertheless, it is a good suggestion.

Comment: I've not used AM for a long time, but is it possible via reflection to get all the mappings, and manually invoking them to trigger the lazy plan compilation for each? (and catching the failures). Essentially performing your own `CompileMappings`, kinda.

Answer (score -1):

There was no quick solution. Resolving this problem was done the old-fashioned way by trial and error: removing profiles and maps until the error disappeared, then re-introducing them one at a time until the error reappeared (effectively performing a binary search). Fortunately, the entire process took less than a day. Here is the summary:

- Removed half the profiles from the configuration until compiling the remaining ones did not exhibit the error. If the error still existed, repeat this step until compiling succeeded.
- Reintroduced half of the removed profiles. If the error returned, I repeated the process from the first step. Otherwise, I removed the added profiles again and use the other half of the removed profiles. I repeated these steps until only one profile remained.
- Since there was not a single profile that produced the error, I repeated the process by keeping the profile containing the map from where the error originated and performed the same steps with all the other profiles.
- When I reduced the set to a related pair of profiles, I was able to repeat the same process with individual maps, eliminating large numbers of maps by educated guess.

The end result was finding a small set of related maps that resulted in mapping a property to the wrong type. AutoMapper had inferred mappings between some properties (through class and map inheritances) that were logical but incorrect. AutoMapper determined that a destination property of one class could be assigned directly from a source property of another class, where the source and destination were derived from the same base class. The generated assignment resulted in the coercion error because there was no constructor on either class to convert an instance of the other.

By analyzing the classes involved, I was finally able to realize that a type map had been omitted. When a new map was added to the configuration that provided a direct mapping from the source type to the destination type, AutoMapper used the new mapping instead of inferring one that the expression compiler was unable to resolve.

Had AutoMapper been able to identify the type map that failed expression compilation, the effort to solve this problem would have been reduced from days to hours.